# Matlab & Java: Execute matlab asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab, asynchronous, synchronous

so, here is my today problem:

First of all, please note that **I do NOT have the Matlab parallel toolbox available**.

I am running java code witch interact with Matlab. Sometime Matlab directly call some java functions, sometimes it is the opposite. In this case, we use a notification system which comes from here:

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events

We then address the notification in proper callbacks.

Here is a simple use case:

- My user select a configuration file using the java interface, loaded into Matlab.
- Using an interface listener, we notify Matlab that the configuration file has been selected, it then run a certain number of functions that will analyzes the file
- Once the analysis is done, it is pushed into the java runtime, which will populate interface tables with the result. This step involve that matlab will call a java function.
- Finally, java request the interface to be switched to an arbitrary decided tab.

This is the order of which things would happen in an ideal world, however, here is the code of the listener actionPerformed method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    Model           wModel      = controller.getModel();
    Window          wWindow     = controller.getWindow();

    MatlabStructure wStructure  = new MatlabStructure();

    if(null != wModel) {
        wModel.readMatlabData(wStructure);
        wModel.notifyMatlab(wStructure, MatlabAction.UpdateCircuit);            
    }

    if(null != wWindow) {
        wWindow.getTabContainer().setSelectedComponent(wWindow.getInfosPannel());
    }
}
```

What happen here, is that, when the *notifyMatlab* method is called, the code does not wait for it to be completed before it continues. So what happen is that the method complete and switch to an empty interface page (*setSelectedComponent*), and then the component is filled with values.

What I would like to, is for java to wait that my notifyMatlab returns a "I have completed !!" signal, and then pursue. Which involves asynchrounous code since Matlab will code java methods during its execution too ...

**So far here is what I tried:**

In the MatlabEventObject class, I added an *isAcknowledge* member, so now the class (which I originaly found in the above link), look like this (I removed all unchanged code from the original class):

```
public class MatlabEventObject extends java.util.EventObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean         isAcknowledged = false;

    public void onNotificationReceived() {
        if (source instanceof MatlabEvent) {

            System.out.println("Catched a MatlabEvent Pokemon !");
            MatlabEvent wSource = (MatlabEvent) source;
            wSource.onNotificationReceived();

        }
    }

    public boolean isAcknowledged() {
        return isAcknowledged;
    }

    public void acknowledge() {
        isAcknowledged = true;
    }
}
```

In the MatlabEvent class, I have added a future task which goal is to wait for acknowledgement, the methods now look like this:

```
public class MatlabEvent {

    private Vector<IMatlabListener>     data            = new Vector<IMatlabListener>();
    private Vector<MatlabEventObject>   matlabEvents    = new Vector<MatlabEventObject>();

    public void notifyMatlab(final Object obj, final MatlabAction action) {

        final Vector<IMatlabListener> dataCopy;
        matlabEvents.clear();

        synchronized (this) {
            dataCopy = new Vector<IMatlabListener>(data);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataCopy.size(); i++) {
            matlabEvents.add(new MatlabEventObject(this, obj, action));
            ((IMatlabListener) dataCopy.elementAt(i)).testEvent(matlabEvents.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void onNotificationReceived() {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();      
        long            timeout = 15;

        System.out.println("Executing runnable.");

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                waitForAcknowledgement(matlabEvents);               
            }

        };          

        try {
            Future<?> task = service.submit(r);
            task.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Notification acknowledged.");   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void waitForAcknowledgement(final Vector<MatlabEventObject> matlabEvents) {

        boolean allEventsAcknowledged = false;
        while(!allEventsAcknowledged) {
            allEventsAcknowledged = true;
            for(MatlabEventObject eventObject : matlabEvents) {

                if(!eventObject.isAcknowledged()) {
                    allEventsAcknowledged = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happen is that I discover that Matlab actually **WAIT** for the java code to be completed. So my *waitForAcknowledgement* method always wait until it timeouts.

In addition, I must say that I have very little knowledge in parallel computing, but I think our java is single thread, so having java waiting for matlab code to complete while matlab is issuing calls to java functions may be an issue. But I can't be sure : ]

If you have any idea on how to solve this issue in a robust way, it will be much much appreciated.

Comment: How is the parallel toolbox of MATLAB relevant? I see purely java code.

Comment: Because I found an hint on another topic that was about taking advantage of the parallels pools of matlab in my callbacks processing function, but I cannot do it.